# Rotation is working while translation is not working at same time in android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, animation, objectanimator

First of all, *please don't declare it as duplicate* because i have been spending time on stackoverflow since last five days and i have read a lot of answers but still not able to achieve this.

I want card flip animation in my application. I tried https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html also but exit animation is not being played there for me.

So i used two frame layouts for two fragments in a Linear Layout and then tried to rotate and translate first frame layout towards left out of screen while rotating and translating next frame layout in from right.First frame is rotating as required but translation is not there.

Please help to make frame layout translate also with rotation so that *next fragment could enter the screen*.

***My code is:***

***activity_card.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

***card_flip_left_out.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:duration="1000" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:duration="800" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationX"
        android:valueTo="-200"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:duration="1000"
        />

</set>
```

***card_flip_right_in.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0" />

    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="1000" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:duration="800" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationX"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:duration="1000"
        />

</set>
```

***CardActivity.java:***

```
public class CardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
                Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    FrameLayout layout1, layout2;
    String visibleFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Digital card");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

        layout1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout1);
        layout2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout2);


        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout1, GeneralDetailsFragment.newInstance());
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout2, AddMoreDetailsFragment.newInstance());
        visibleFragment = "layout1";
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Animator anim1 = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        Animator anim2 = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,R.animator.card_flip_right_in);

        if(visibleFragment.equals("layout2"))
        {
            anim1.setTarget(layout2);
            anim2.setTarget(layout1);
            anim1.start();
            anim2.start();
            visibleFragment = "layout1";
        }
        else
        {
            anim1.setTarget(layout1);
            anim2.setTarget(layout2);
            anim1.start();
            anim2.start();
            visibleFragment = "layout2";
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

below is xml file for animation (left to right with rotation) and start animation on view. And make changes as per you need.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

        <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="500"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:repeatCount="5"
            android:toDegrees="359" />
        <translate
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fromXDelta="0%p"        //For Y - android:fromYDelta="0%p" also -value 
            android:toXDelta="100%p"        //For Y - android:toYDelta="50%p"   
            android:repeatCount="0"
            android:duration="3000">
        </translate>
  </set>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i have already tried this animation api but i am not able to rotate along y-axis only through this code.... i want rotation along y-axis only which is fine through my code but at same time translation is not working

Answer (score 0):

I found a *different and pretty simple* way to achieve card flip animation [here](https://github.com/balesz/android-tutorial-CardFlipAnimation) . This animation is not for replacing or adding fragment using `FragmentTransaction` but for two frame layouts which already contain corresponding `Fragment`.

Sample code is:

```
public void flip(final View front, final View back, final int duration) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.playSequentially(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(front, "rotationY", 90).setDuration(duration / 2),
                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(front, "visibility", View.GONE).setDuration(0),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(back, "rotationY", -90).setDuration(0),
                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(back, "visibility", View.VISIBLE).setDuration(0),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(back, "rotationY", 0).setDuration(duration / 2)
        );
        set.start();
    }
    else {
        front.animate().rotationY(90).setDuration(duration / 2).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                front.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                back.setRotationY(-90);
                back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                back.animate().rotationY(0).setDuration(duration / 2).setListener(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Great !! Putting solution here.